# SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported using groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation, geopandas

Could you please help me to solve this issue in my code, as the spatial join using pandas (groupby(), agg()) it give me the below error:

I have a data frame df and I use several columns from it to groupby:
n the below way I almost get the table (data frame) that I need. What is missing is an additional column that contains number of rows in each group. In other words, I have mean but I also would like to know how many number were used to get these means.

In short: How do I get group-wise statistics for a dataframe?

Code:

```
def bin_the_midpoints(bins, midpoints):
    b = bins.copy()
    m = midpoints.copy()
    reindexed = b.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'bins_index'})
    joined = gpd.tools.sjoin(reindexed, m)
    bin_stats = joined.groupby('bins_index')['offset']\
                      .agg({'fold': len, 'min_offset': np.min})
    return gpd.GeoDataFrame(b.join(bin_stats))
bin_stats = bin_the_midpoints(bins, midpoints)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SpecificationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [103], in <cell line: 9>()
      6     bin_stats = joined.groupby('bins_index')['offset']\
      7                       .agg({'fold': len, 'min_offset': np.min})
      8     return gpd.GeoDataFrame(b.join(bin_stats))
----> 9 bin_stats = bin_the_midpoints(bins, midpoints)

Input In [103], in bin_the_midpoints(bins, midpoints)
      4 reindexed = b.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'bins_index'})
      5 joined = gpd.tools.sjoin(reindexed, m)
----> 6 bin_stats = joined.groupby('bins_index')['offset']\
      7                   .agg({'fold': len, 'min_offset': np.min})
      8 return gpd.GeoDataFrame(b.join(bin_stats))

File ~\anaconda3\envs\GeoSynapps\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py:271, in SeriesGroupBy.aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    267 elif isinstance(func, abc.Iterable):
    268     # Catch instances of lists / tuples
    269     # but not the class list / tuple itself.
    270     func = maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
--> 271     ret = self._aggregate_multiple_funcs(func)
    272     if relabeling:
    273         # error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type
    274         # "Optional[List[str]]", variable has type "Index")
    275         ret.columns = columns  # type: ignore[assignment]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\GeoSynapps\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py:307, in SeriesGroupBy._aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg)
    301 def _aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg) -> DataFrame:
    302     if isinstance(arg, dict):
    303 
    304         # show the deprecation, but only if we
    305         # have not shown a higher level one
    306         # GH 15931
--> 307         raise SpecificationError("nested renamer is not supported")
    309     elif any(isinstance(x, (tuple, list)) for x in arg):
    310         arg = [(x, x) if not isinstance(x, (tuple, list)) else x for x in arg]

SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

You must read more about agg method in pandas. Easily you can add many calculation to this method.

For example you can write:

```py
df.groupby(by=[...]).agg({'col1': ['count', 'sum', 'min']})
```

Comment: Thank you @Alireza, could you please have a look on my code and flag the error and let me know how I correct it... Many thanks